# Saving script run time in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, runtime, ssms

I have some scripts that run overnight and I'm looking to start improving their run time and being able to report on this.
Therefore I'm looking for a way to add a column within an SSMS table to show how long the script took to run.
Example -

```
Script          Date Run     Time Taken
Script 1        01/01/2022     2000
Script 2        02/01/2022     5000
```

My aim is to grow this table overtime to show the improvement.
I can see loads of stuff online about the results pane but nothing about including run time in the actual query.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: This is down to you to log. Create a table and capture the datetime when the process starts and ends then you can report on it. If you're running them using SQL Agent the duration is stored in msdb.

Comment: There’s no magic, you’ll have to log start and end times yourself. For individual queries you can rely on things like query store but for a larger batch / process you’re on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the perfect solution -

```
DECLARE @Timer datetime
SELECT @Timer = getdate()

--Start time
SELECT @Timer as QueryStartTime

--- Actual Query Goes Here
SELECT top 1000 * from agreement
--- End of query

--End Time
SELECT getdate() as QueryEndTime

insert into dbo.runtimes
SELECT 'xx' AS ScriptName,
    CONVERT(date, GETDATE())AS RunDate,
    @Timer as QueryStartTime,
    getdate() as QueryEndTime,
datediff(ms, @Timer, getdate()) as TimeInMS
```

Thanks!